# How to convert complex Object to Json String

Tags: json, object, gson, multimap

I have following class defined:

```
public class ClassObjectTwo {
Long a;
Long b;
}

public class ClassObjectThree{
Long c;
Long d;
}

public class ClassObject{
  private final ClassObjectTwo obj1;
  private final ClassObjectTwo obj2;
  private final ClassObjectTwo obj3;
  private final Multimap<String, ClassObjectThree> obj4;
}

ClassObject classObj;

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(classObj);
return jsonString;
```

JsonString is not returning anything, How to define Object of object to convert into JSON String ?

How to use InstanceCreator here ?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, what the issue here is, when you say, it's not returning anything. Try making use of GsonBuilder.

you could use - GsonBuilder, and enable the complexMapKeySerialization as below.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Instant.class, new InstantConverter()).enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
        .setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

Since the Gson uses, toString() methods, for forming the JSON, make sure to use them.

```
public class ClassObject{
  private final ClassObjectTwo obj1;
  private final ClassObjectTwo obj2;
  private final ClassObjectTwo obj3;
  private final Multimap<String, ClassObjectThree> obj4;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return new ToStringBuilder(this)
            .append("obj1", obj1)
            .append("obj2", obj2)
            .append("obj3", obj3)
            .append("obj4", obj4)
            .toString();
    }
  }
```